# React app breaks when ag grid cellEditor popup is visible and the component is unmounting

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

This is the UI for the ag grid. Right now I have pinned the first row and it is editable so it basically adds records in the ag grid. When the popup is open and i try to unmount the component to move to other component it gives me the following error. and My react app breaks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the coldef that i am using/

```
    {
  field: 'openingBrace',
  colId: 'openingBrace',
  cellRenderer: 'CheckBoxRenderer',
  cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
  checkboxSelection: true,
  cellEditorPopup: true,
  cellEditorParams: {
    values: ["true", "false"],
  },
},
```

AG grid configuration is as follows:

```
      <AgGridReact
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    frameworkComponents={frameworkComponents}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    rowData={rowData}
    getRowStyle={getRowStyle}
    pinnedTopRowData={[inputRow]}
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
    onCellEditingStopped={onCellEditingStopped}
    pagination={true}
    paginationPageSize={10}
    animateRows={true}
    rowSelection={"multiple"}
    suppressRowClickSelection={true}
    onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
    rowModelType={"serverSide"}
    serverSideInfiniteScroll={true}
  ></AgGridReact>
```